# Loopback: How to define a property with an array of strings in Loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I have the following model in a loopback application, that will be persisted in a MongoDB:

### Model

Name Coffeshop:

- Id
- Name (string)
- City (String)

### Question:

Now i want to be able to store a list of strings in a new property called "tags":

- Tags (Array of string)

There is no relation to other models necessary. I need just a plain flat list of strings.

How can i achieve this?

### Code:

```
{
  "name": "CoffeeShop",
  "plural": "CoffeeShops",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "city": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats easy:

```
{
  "name": "CoffeeShop",
  "plural": "CoffeeShops",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "city": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "tags": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ],
      "required": false
    }
},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```